# Good practice to add to set in while condition?

Tags: java, while-loop, set

I am trying to add a random number to a set. If it is already in the set, then the loop should continue and try again.

Which is better practice,

```
do {
  nextChosenInt = rand.nextInt(48) + 1;
  addFailed = !chosenInts.add(nextChosenInt);
}
while (addFailed);
```

or

```
do {
    nextChosenInt = rand.nextInt(48) + 1;
}
while (!chosenInts.add(nextChosenInt));
```

Comment: Sorry, I should probably modify my post as I didn't actually implement it this way. I was just concerned with the condition and whether adding to the set within that was good practice. nextChosenInt is declared before the loop and initialised in the first iteration.

Comment: Tbh I don't see much of a difference when it comes to performance.

Comment: You could also just do `while (!chosenInts.add(rand.nextInt(48) + 1));`. Without more context, though, I'm not sure what prevents the map filling up with all the possible random numbers and ending up with an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would vote for the second option here, with a slight change.

You are utilising the fact that the `.add` method returns a boolean which is a beneficial, in that you don't need to have a redundant flag variable which, from the context of your code, serves no other purpose than just terminating the loop.

Personally however I would choose to extract:

```
!chosenInts.add(nextChosenInt)
```

into its own method which is more descriptive and readable. By doing this, you are allowing anyone to understand this condition with no prior knowledge of the Collections API.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E)), "if this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false." Regardless of when you add to the set, if the set already contains the element, it would remain unchanged. Thus, it doesn't really make a difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Neither since sets can't hold duplicates.  Just do it until `set` has a desired number of elements. But you could also do something like this.

```
        Random rand = new Random();
        int next = 50;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           next = rand.nextInt(48) + next+1;
           set.add(next);  
        }
```

They are all unique the first time (but not entirely random).  To add a number that is not in the set, the following is possible.

```
        int size = set.size();
        while (set.size() == size) {
           set.add(rand.nextInt(48));
        }
```

Comment: We all know sets can't hold duplicates and so does OP, I think you misread the question. OP wants to generate and add one random number that doesn't exist in the set already.

Comment: Ok.  I thought the OP simply wanted to generate N number of unique numbers.